# Can we enable keepalive from client side socket also?

Tags: c++, tcp, network-programming

When I did `netstat -anto`, I got the following output

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       Timer

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1169              127.0.0.1:40238            ESTABLISHED off (0.00/0/0)
```

I guess off means that the keepalive timer is off.

Can we enable keepalive from client side socket? Or it can be enabled only for server-side code? How to enable it from the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable `SO_KEEPALIVE` from any side. Just remember that the default ping-time and timeout is very long, the ping time is by default usually two hours, for example.